# Is it function overloading or overriding?

Tags: c++, overloading, overriding

Is it function overloading or overriding or something else ? ( hello function )

```
class A {

public:
    void hello(int x) { cout << "A" << endl; }

};

class B : public A {

public:
    void hello() { cout << "B" << endl; }

};

void main() {

    B obj;
    obj.hello();

}
```

Comment: fun fact: while in C++ the function in the subclass hides the base class implementation completely, in C# this is a valid way to provide an overload in a subclass, with the base class function staying accessible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's neither, it's function **hiding**.

Declaring a non-virtual function with the same name (even if the signature is different) in a derived class hides the base class implementation completely.

To still have access to `A::hello`, you can do the following:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    using A::hello;
    void hello() { cout << "B" << endl; }
};
```

#### Overriding:

```
struct A
{
   virtual void foo() {}
};
struct B : public A
{
   /*virtual*/ void foo() {}
};
```

#### Overloading:

```
struct A
{
   void foo() {}
   void foo(int) {}
};
```

Comment: Can you give me a very simple example about overriding, please !

Comment: @faressoft: That's not hard to find online.

Comment: @faressoft to get overriding in C++ you have to use `virtual`. I'll add an answer with an example.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore : if i declared a function with the same signature in the base class and the derived class. Is it an overriding ?

Comment: @faressoft it the function is virtual, yes, if not, it's hiding.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore : thank you very much. but what "virtual" exactely does. I can't find any different.

Comment: @faressoft virtual is a key concept in OOP and requires much more explanation than a SO comment box. It's explained in all C++ books and tutorials, and I'm sure you'll find the answer to this and more on Google. Come back to ask a question after you've read the documentation and have a specific question.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore : thank you very mush. but why our teacher didn't talk about something called virtual today in the Overriding lesson. She told as ( same name and signature in a base class. That is overriding ).

Comment: @faressoft if you're learning C++ and your teacher said that, she's wrong. Is this a college course?

Comment: She told as my code in the quiestion ^ ... is overloading :0. That is wrong right ( function hiding ) !

Comment: She told as it is an overloading when we use ( using keyword )

Comment: @faressoft yes it's wrong. It's not overloading, it's hiding.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void Foo() { std::cout << "Base\n"; };
};

struct Derived : Base {
    virtual void Foo() { std::cout << "Derived\n"; };
    // same name and signature as a virtual function in a base class,
    // therefore this overrides that function. 'virtual' is optional in
    // the derived class (but you should use it).
};
```

C++11 adds a way to ensure your function overrides:

```
struct Derived : Base {
    virtual void Foo() override { std::cout << "Derived\n"; };
};
```

Now if the method `Foo` is not overriding something then you will get an error.

```
struct Base {
   void Foo();
};

struct Derived : Base {
   virtual void Foo() override; // error, Derived::Foo is hiding Base::Foo, not overriding 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is neither.

Overriding is a function with the same signature (same name, parameters and return value) in a subclass. Overloading is a function with the same name but different parameters.

Comment: That's wrong. Overriding requires virtual functions, overloading can meam more than that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not Overloaded Function because in Function Overloading either number of parameters or type of parameters should differ.For example :

```
void show(int a,int b);
void show(int a);
void show(char a,char b);
```

And neither it is Function Overriding because in Overridden function prototype must be same.For example :
Base class and Derived class having function 
`void show();
        //function prototype must be same`